# How to pass php data to kinetic js

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, wordpress

Hello i have to set canvas image dynamically 
Below is code for Wordpress

```
$image= http://captoons2.se7enmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/eden-apple-180x138.jpg","http://captoons2.se7enmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/gravesite-180x138.png"
```

This is my main.js code

```
var data = {
"images": [ "images here"
],
"captions":[    ]};
```

In the above js code i want to pass $image data in "images" i have tryied wp_localize_script() bt it not working

Answer (score 0):

I followed the code from the tutorial [HTML5 Canvas Image Loader Tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/) and applied it to my theme as follows:

- Enqueue and localize in `functions.php`:

  ```
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_kinetics_so_24031697' );

  function load_kinetics_so_24031697() {
      $path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/';
      wp_register_script( 'kinetic', $path . 'kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js' );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'my-kinetic', $path . 'my-kinetic.js', array( 'kinetic' ), null, true ); // on footer, important
      wp_localize_script( 'my-kinetic', 'kinets', array( 
          'images' => array(
              'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
              'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
          )
      ));
  }
  ```
- Add the `canvas` div to `single.php`:

  ```
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
  ```
- Small adaptation from the original code in `my-kinetic.js` to pull the data from the localized object. Load the sources from `kinets.images` and iterate through the object numeric keys (instead of key names):

  ```
  function loadImages(sources, callback) {
      var images = {};
      var loadedImages = 0;
      var numImages = 0;
      // get num of sources
      for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
      }
      for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
              if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                  callback(images);
              }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
      }
  }
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  loadImages(kinets.images, function(images) {
      context.drawImage(images[0], 100, 30, 200, 137);
      context.drawImage(images[1], 350, 55, 93, 104);
  });
  ```